# How to add a integer to a string?

Tags: python, string

So I got this

```
      itemIds1 = ('2394328')
      itemIds2 = ('6546345')
      count2 = 1
      itemIdsCount = ('itemIds' + count2)
      while (count2 < 2):
                #Do stuff
                count2 = count2 + 1
```

I'm not sure if I explained this correct. But in line 4 I want to make the string to equal itemIds1 then once it looks make it equal itemsIds2.

If you don't know I'm clearly new to python so if you can explain what to do clearly that would be awesome.

Comment: `itemIdsCount = "itemIds%d" % count2` i think would do what you want, no?

Answer (score 3):

Here are possible options:

1. Use `%s`

   > itemIdsCount = 'itemIds%s' + count
2. Cast integer to string first

   > itemIdsCount = 'itemIds' + str(count)
3. Use `.format()` method

   > itemIdsCount = 'itemIds{}'.format(count)
4. If you have python 3.6, you can use F-string (Literal String Interpolation)

   > count = 1
   >
   > itemIdsCount = f'itemIds{count}'

Comment: Don't forget about f-strings in Python >=3.6! `f'itemIds{count2}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format`, i.e.:

```
  count2 = 1
  itemIdsCount = ('itemIds{}'.format(count2))
  while (count2 < 2):
            #Do stuff
            count2 += 1 # it's simpler like this
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will create the string you need:

```
itemIdsCount = "itemIds%d" % count2
```

so you can look up python for strings, and see how you can use %s,%d and others to inject what comes after.

As an additionalNote, if you need to append multiple items you would need to say something like this:

```
itemIdsCount = "Id:%d Name:%s" % (15, "Misha")
```

Answer (score -1):

if you need to equal string and integer maybe you should use str(x) or int(x). in this case itemIdsCount = ('itemIds' + str(count2))